# Gmake deferred simple variable expansion inside a macro function

Tags: gnu-make, variable-assignment

Background: a formula for *deferred simple variable expansion* is [here](https://make.mad-scientist.net/deferred-simple-variable-expansion/).

The idea is to assign a variable once, but only if gmake actually uses it.

```
OUTPUT = $(eval OUTPUT := $$(shell some-comand))$(OUTPUT)
```

This speeds up *make* when the calculation is slow. Which is nice.

However, repeating that pattern for numerous variables would lead to a pile of ugly in the make-file.

I'd like to wrap that concept in a macro function. Pseudo-code:

```
X = $(call LAZY_ONCE,foo)
Y = $(call LAZY_ONCE,bar)

LAZY_ONCE=*some variant of the above formula*
```

Is this possible?

The formula depends on a specific and fragile order-of-evaluation. I don't see a way of wrapping it into a macro-function with breaking that order.  But maybe there's some clever trick I'm missing.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expect a line like `X = $(call LAZY_ONCE,foo)` to do.  maybe you could provide a more realistic example and show what the result should be.  There's clearly no way that you can set the variable `X` using this model, since the `call` function cannot know what the name is of the variable on the right-hand side.  You'd have to, at the very least, pass the name of the variable to be assigned to `call`.

Comment: @MadScientist That section is pseudo-code ... I've tagged it as such.

Comment: @MadScientist More important is your point on call() knowing the variable name. That's probably a worse issue than the evaluation order. Passing a variable-name as a variable, then de-referencing it at the correct moments ... even if all this could be done, it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I certainly understand that it's pseudo code.  What I'm saying is your question doesn't provide enough details about what you really want to do, to formulate a response.  If you could provide some pseudo-code that more closely resembled some actual, real thing that you wanted to do it would be helpful.

Comment: Since the variable value _must_ contain the name of the variable to be assigned (see the `OUTPUT` version and how it appears in the left-hand side of the assignment) there's no way to avoid providing that to the `call` function, since it has to be placed into the resulting value.